# Can I reject notifications when I uninstall Progressive Web App on the home screen?

Tags: push-notification, permissions, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am in trouble with the operation of Progressive Web Apps.

First, I pressed "Add to Home Screen" on the web, added the application to the home screen, and gave permission for push notification.

After that, I uninstalled Progressive Web Apps from the home screen, I expected that the notification will not arrive, but in fact it gets notified.

Can I detect uninstallation and reject push notifications?

I tried searching including the [following site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker).
For example, but there is nothing expected of event or status.

Although it is an attachment of the home screen after uninstallation,
A Google Chrome icon is displayed in the notification bar.
[home screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5RlY.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment in response to the other answer, I figure you are building a progressive web app and want to implement this feature (turning off notifications on removal from the home screen) in your own PWA?

Currently (October 2017) there is no way for a PWA to detect if a user has removed it from their home screen. There is a way for the PWA to detect if it is uninstalled (as in the service worker is removed from the browser all together) but that is something totally different. You aren't uninstalling the PWA when you remove it from the home screen, you're just removing a shortcut. The PWA is still installed in the user's browser. They could still manually visit the site and your PWA would still be working.

Maybe this will become a feature in the future. For right now there isn't even a way to create a hack that would help.

Comment: Nathan Heffley, exactly what I want to know! Thank you!
It is a pity that I do not have the function I am looking for, but I'd like to wait for future implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate to the web app in question using Chrome for Android, either directly or by tapping on a notification, you can manually adjust its permissions by tapping on the "Lock" icon next to the location bar, then choosing "SITE SETTINGS", and then making changes there.

[image]

The specific steps to do this would vary if you're using a browser other than Chrome.

Comment: Jeff Posnick, Thanks for the answer!
If there is no other way I will adopt the answer method, but if possible, I would like to be able to reject notifications as soon as uninstalling.
Because I do not think that this operation is generally perceived.